# Is minimizing the degree of an approximating polynomial convex?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, relaxations

Let $f(x) : \{-1, 1\}^n \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $|f(x)| \le 1$. I would like to find the minimum-degree (multivariate) polynomial $P(x)$ such that:

$$|P(x) - f(x)| \le \epsilon$$
for every $x \in S \subseteq \{-1, 1\}^n$. Is there a convex relaxation for the degree of $P$, i.e., some convex objective function that gives a minimum-degree polynomial when the optimum is attained?

Answer (score 0):

I assume $\epsilon$ is given and fixed.

I think you can solve this using linear programming (LP).
Set
$$P(x) = \sum_{\alpha \in \mathbb{N}^n} p_{\alpha} x^\alpha,$$
where
$$x^\alpha := \prod_{i = 1}^n x^\alpha_i. $$
If $\text{deg}(P) = d$, then
\begin{align}
\label{eqn_1}
p_\alpha = 0 \quad \forall \alpha \text{ satisfying } \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha > d.
\end{align}
You want to find the polynomial $P$ that satisfies your condition of approximating $f$. I'd solve this by first fixing the degree of $P$ to $k = 1$. Then look for coefficients $p_{\alpha}$ that satisfy
$$ f(x)-\epsilon \leq P(x) \leq \epsilon + f(x) \quad \forall x \in S \text{ and } \text{deg}(P) = k.$$
Note that for each $x \in S$, you get a linear constraint on the coefficients $p_\alpha$. The constraint $\text{deg}(P) = k$ is also linear on $p_\alpha$, since it evaluates to setting certain coefficients to $0$. If this problem does not have a solution for degree $k=1$, simply increase $k$ by $1$, and try again. Whenever you find a feasible solution/polynomial, stop the recursion. You have found your minimal degree polynomial.

This approach, specifically the LP, is rather brute force; you can probably improve it by using some ideas from polynomial interpolation. For example, if the degree $k > |S|$, then   $P(x)$ can equal $f(x)$ for all $x \in S$.

Comment: I was not interested in actually solving the optimization problem computationally, but rather finding a dual program for it. Can one define a witness for the non-existence of a polynomial of degree $\le k$?

Comment: Such a polynomial of degree $\leq k$ does not exist, if and only if the corresponding LP (or polyhedron) that I described is infeasible (empty). There exist 'witnesses' of infeasible LP programmes, see for example Farkas Lemma.

Comment: I get your point, and usage of Farkas' Lemma. And using the condition, I can witness the non-existence of a polynomial of deg P with a feasible solution to the dual problem. But does "strong duality" hold in that case? On quote because your LP does not have an objective function, so even weak duality is not really well-defined.

Comment: What would 'strong duality' mean in terms of your problem? And why would you care? Farkas lemma gives you a certificate for the non-existence of a certain degree $k$ polynomial. Does that not answer your question? If you care about interpreting it via LP duality, you may as well attach some dummy objective to the coefficients, say maximizing the sum of all coefficients.